# TigerVNC segmentation fault when running from systemd unit

Tags: vnc

If I run `sudo systemctl tigervncserver@:2`, the server segmentation faults:

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.12.0 - built 2022-03-25 17:06
Copyright (C) 1999-2021 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12101003, X.Org


Fri Jul 14 19:45:34 2023
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5902
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
[mi] mieq: warning: overriding existing handler (nil) with 0x56355e466400 for event 2
[mi] mieq: warning: overriding existing handler (nil) with 0x56355e466400 for event 3
3NI3X0 New Xtigervnc server 'myserver:2 (user2)' on port 5902 for display :2.
3NI3X0 Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /home/user2/.vnc/passwd :2 to connect to the VNC server.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
X connection to :2 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

The service uses `ExecStart=/usr/libexec/tigervncsession-start %i`, so if I run `/usr/libexec/tigervncsession-start :2` it should behave similarly, right?

But in that case it doesn't hit the fault and runs normally, which makes it difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the user being logged in at the console. It appears there is some kind of exclusivity. The user can be logged in at the console without the VNC server running, or logged in via VNC without being able to sign in at the console.